# PrestaShop 1.5 adding PHP (reCaptcha)

Tags: php, prestashop, recaptcha

currently I'm working on an outdated PrestaShop instance in version 1.5. There is a requirement to integrate Google's reCaptcha. So far that was easy. Except the Respond code, which is a PHP script, does not work yet.
Is there an easy way to integrate a PHP code into such a PrestaShop? It has to be loaded before the HTML code.

The main issue is, that I have no idea how to implement a PHP-Code in a PrestaShop 1.5. There aren't any tutorials or documentations anymore. And most hints are for codes inside CMS-pages, but I need it above the head.

The code I want to implement looks like that:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submitMessage'])){
        $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
        $data = [
            'secret' => "***",
            'response' => $_POST['token']
        ];

        $options = array(
            'http' => array(
                'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data)
            )
        );

        $context = stream_context_create($options);
        $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($response);
    }
?>
```

I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: To add this: I tried the Slidecaptcha. It doesn't help and an upgrade of PrestaShop isn't possible either.

Comment: its pretty simple how it works so an example for a CMS or whatnot will be the same. basically the user verifies clientside, a token is issued by recapcha, the token is appended to your form as an input, you then use that to do the request to verify as part of your validation checks, its not a separate step

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I understand the theory behind that but the issue is, that this all requiers to add PHP to the page. What's not easy in PrestaShop 1.5.

Comment: Where are you trying to add reCaptcha?

Comment: @joseantgv do you mean on which site or in what part of the code?

Comment: @KendelVentonda in which part of the code :)